# How to get resources path?

Tags: iphone

I run my app on Simulator in XCode and it works fine but when I try to run it on the device it doesn't work.
I figured out that it doesn't open some files.
(I don't know if it gets wrong path or maybe the files aren't copied)

Before I open my files I get their path like that:

```
const char* Pobierz_sciezke(const char  *tytul_c)
{
 NSString *tytul = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: tytul_c];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tytul];

 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs])
 {
  NSString *myPathInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tex_dane" ofType:@"txt"];
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 }

 NSLog(@"%@",myPathDocs);

 const char *sciezka;
 sciezka = [myPathDocs UTF8String];
 return sciezka;
}
```

Is this code ok?

Maybe I should add my resources in a different way? Change project settings?

Comment: Are these files added to the app by the user or do they all exist inside the project? If they're added, how are they added? To what path? If they're not, can't you just do [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"txt"] (to get "foo.txt")?